# Check if NFT tokenURI is an image or a video

Tags: javascript, nft, react

Is there a way to check if the file I'm loading as a URI is an image or a video.

so that I can use 'img' tag for the images and 'video' tag for the videos.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could examine the headers from the webserver/IPFS server which will often indicate the type of the object in the stream. Alternatively you could use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

Comment: hey thanks for the reply!
Can you give an example, how do I find the mime-type of the  [uri](https://storage.opensea.io/files/2e48ae3c7d6968aaad0a818a22466070.mp4#t=0.001)  in react.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354763/how-do-i-get-http-headers-in-react-js